# Google places autocomplete showing different results depending on key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I type the query `Mountainview chem-dry` on the example page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete I get results back. When I open it in jsfiddle, put in my own api key, and run it again, I get no results back. I've looked at the requests and besides the keys and some other odd query params (`1d-33.936405187906715` and such), the requests are identical. The only difference in the code is the api key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mountainview Chem-Dry is defined as a Service Area Business. Please note that Service Area Businesses should not be available via place autocomplete.

These places typically have 0,0 coordinates in responses and there is no sense to show places without exact coordinates on the map.

If you look into network activity when you execute a sample page with Google's API key you will see that place ID for Mountainview Chem-Dry is ChIJG-kOFY4NiYgRc2BFHIDJ7eg.

Now execute the place details request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJG-kOFY4NiYgRc2BFHIDJ7eg&key=YOUR_API_KEY

You will see the following in the response:

```
...
"geometry":{
  "location":{
    "lat":0,
    "lng":0
  },
  "location_type":"APPROXIMATE"
},
...
```

that indicates that this is a SAB. Also note where the example displays this place (it's 0,0 coordinate in Atlantic ocean close to Africa)

[image]

This is really confusing. I guess Google's sample page shouldn't use the internal API key with ability to show all places, because ordinary API keys that you can generate in developer console filter out all SABs.

Comment: I thought it had something to do with it being an SAB, but wasn't quite sure if the key used in the sample page had extra permissions or powers or whatever. That makes sense, though.